# Sorting a array in alphabetical order in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, foreach, explode

```
<?php
$string = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
$string = explode("", $string);
sort($string);
foreach ($string as $val) {
    echo $val."<br>";
}
?>
```

I want this to output:
a
b
c
...
but how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current call to `explode()` isn't working -- it doesn't accept an empty first argument. Try using `str_split()` instead:

```
$string = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
$array = str_split($string, 1);
sort($array);
foreach ($array as $val) {
    echo $val."<br>";
}
```